# How to list all excluded files in git?

Tags: git, repository

Over the weekend I was working on my git repository to exclude some files.  This morning it dawned on me that I need to add those patterns to the gitignore file, but... I don't remember all the files I excluded.

Is there a way to get git to show me all the files it is excluding?

Answer (score 1):

you should try:

```
git status --ignored
```